# Execute function if url does not contain a string from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying run a script if URL doesn't contain specific string. Here is what i have so far:

```
var ignorePages = ['page1','page2','page3'];

if (window.location.href.indexOf($.inArray(ignorePages)) === -1) {
    // do something
}
```

But this is not working. I would like to test if the string is found in array and if not, execute. Searched the SO Q/A but couldnt find a solution via array using jQuery's `inArray`.

Comment: did you look at the documentation for $.inArray?

Comment: That's not even remotely how inArray works.

Comment: Start by reading jQuery's own documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: or skip that and look at the mdn for Array methods. you don't need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for pointing in right directions. I've solved it with correct usage of inArray:

```
var ignorePages = ['/page1','/page2','/page3'];
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;

if ($.inArray(currentUrl, ignorePages) === -1) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org). I also think you may want to use `location.pathname` instead of `location.href`. Anyhow, this is how I would do it.

```
import { contains } from 'underscore';

let blacklist = ['/splash', '/login', '/feed' ];

if (! contains(blacklist, window.location.pathname) {
  /* do stuff here */
}
```